# Is there a step through debug tool for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, debugging

I am new to Laravel, and I was wondering if there is a step through debug tool for Laravel, where I can set up break points.. etc, just like Visual Studio with C/C++/C#... etc .

Comment: As far as I'm aware all major IDEs that support PHP (e.g. VS Code, PhpStorm) support this as long as PHP is set up correctly to allow debugging, typically by enabling xdebug and configuring it correctly. If you have specific questions on how to do this after you have chosen an IDE that can do this and went through the specific instructions on how to do this then you can ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, xdebug will allow you to do that. However, there are all sorts of tools for debugging Laravels specifically that may be of more use. Debugbar, ray, tinker, Tinkerwell just to name a few.

Comment: While you are right, you are not 100% right. Those you mentioned do not allow you to `breakpoint` (what the author wants), the only solution is `xdebug` and that is not a composer package but a php extension/module

Comment: I understand that was just giving him options.

Comment: Yes yes, again, I did not say you are not right, just that those options will not allow to breakpoint, and that is what the user is looking for specifically